# Search with * or variable in Sublime

Tags: html, sublimetext3, sublimetext

I need to find all `<p>*any text here*</p>` in my HTML file. How do I do it in Sublime?

Thanks!

Comment: you can use regex to find this in sublime text. See : http://docs.sublimetext.info/en/latest/search_and_replace/search_and_replace_overview.html

Comment: don't say "thanks"; just upvote when something is useful. Like I'm doing now.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:

```
<p>((?s).*?)</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Press Ctrl+shift+F in sublime Text and, And in bottom-left corner you will find Regular Expression Button (On hovering you will get it) and then type your word in "Find:" Box followed by " * "

Eg:  any text here*